# AMD Epyc 7452 having CPU base clock as max clock speed & not boosting to boost clock?

Tags: performance, amd, cpu-frequency, proxmox

I have an [AMD Epyc 7452](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-epyc-7452) CPU on an [ASRock Rack ROMED6U-2L2T](https://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=ROMED6U-2L2T) board running Proxmox 7 a linux system and running `cpupower frequency-info` reveals the following:

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 1.50 GHz - 2.35 GHz
  available frequency steps:  2.35 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.50 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.50 GHz and 2.35 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 1.50 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    Boost States: 0
    Total States: 3
    Pstate-P0:  2350MHz
    Pstate-P1:  2000MHz
    Pstate-P2:  1500MHz
```

This CPU however is, according to its data sheet, able to boost to **3.35ghz**, which I *think* I have never seen it do.

In the Bios I can only set the Core Performance Boost to 'Auto' or 'Disabled' (it is set to 'Auto') and looks like this:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to get the CPU to boost to its (advertised) max clock speed and/or where could the culprit be.. is it the bios that's causing this or is it a missing configuration somewhere in Proxmox / linux?

Comment: What's under Performance (the first option)?

Answer (score 0):

> The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use within this range

The issue could come from the fact that the `ondemand` and not the `performance` CPU governor is used.

Either you manually switched, or maybe you're missing a few updates from that Proxmox VE 7 host, as IIRC, PVE 7 initially switched to a new CPU governor, but it showed that it was not yet ready (or at least a good new default) for server/virtualization, so it was switched back to `performance` again a bit after the PVE 7.0 release via a kernel update.